# Which is Faster regarding Android Images IO

Tags: java, android, xml, image

Which is faster, to recieve images as JPG from server, and save it, then show it in a ListView or what ever

OR

receive images in an XML (as encoded String) from server, then decode it, then show it in a ListView (or even save it then show it from memory)

what is the best way (regarding performance) in transfering images FROM a server TO an android device

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where the limitation is. If the bandwidth of your connection is very small try to transfer as few bytes as possible. However, high compression usually costs more CPU, so if CPU power is limiting you it may be better to use a lower compression.

I am not sure what you mean by "receive images in an XML". Is it some vector format like SVG? That would normally be much smaller than a raster image (especially for large sizes).

To sum up, you will need to do some experiments to find out what works best in your case.

Comment: encoding an image to an xml file, then send this xml file throw a web service to the android device

Comment: @EL-conteDe-monteTereBentikh raster image = each pixel is represented by its color; vector image = geometric primitives (lines, circles, ...) are represented by their coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get the image URL from the server and then download the image using some image managing library like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader or google's volley. These kind of libraries highly configurable and taking care of all the aspects of managing a bitmap.

Comment: you mean that this is faster than the following steps --- (1) encode the images to an xml from the server side (2) send it to the android device (3) let the android device decode this image (4) download it <if i understand you correctly, to save it on the sd or memory> ... which approach is faster, or are both the same ?

Comment: As i told you the fastest way is to store all your images on the server then just download them from the server using the library i provided(that will manage all the bitmap's creation and recycling aspects)